# laravel rendering section no passing parameters data

Tags: laravel, parameters, rendering, laravel-blade

i have a problem passing variable during the rendering of only a section
All works good but array of data passed to the section('sidebar') view create an error ($data doesn't exist)
My blade files are

Default.blade.php

```
    ..other html code before..
<body>
    @include('includes.header')

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            @yield('sidebar')
            <!-- main content -->
            @include('includes.main')

        </div>

        <footer class="row">
            @include('includes.footer')
        </footer>

    </div>
</body>
..other code after..
```

home.blade.php

```
    @extends('layouts.default')
@section('sidebar')
    @include('includes.sidebar')
@stop
```

sidebar.blade.php

```
   ..other html code before..

<h2>The current UNIX timestamp is {{ time() }}.</h2>

<ul>
@isset($data)
   @foreach ($data as $item)
    <li class="nav-item">  {{$item->polizza}}</li>
   @endforeach
@endisset
</ul>
..other html code after..
```

Controller Method search

```
public function search(Request $request){
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data = Customers::select('id','contr_nom','email','targa','cliente')
            ->where('polizza',request('polizza')) 
            ->get();
        return view('pages.home',$data)->renderSections()['sidebar'];
        }
        //return json_encode($data);
    }
```

I know that array $data is good because i try return just JSON and i know that just sidebar refresh because timestamp change.
But $data is not passed to sidebar section refreshed!!
Why?
Thks a lot

Comment: in reality i saw now that the sidebar is recreated in the body of the table that i have, but this would be another problem that i will think later :D now the parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, you just need to send the variable in a form that will be recognized.  I'll break it out to an extreme, to help understand the parts, but you can easily recombine for shorter code.

```
 $view = view('pages.home', compact('data')); // Compact with the text name ('data') sends the variable through

 $sections = $view->renderSections(); // returns an associative array of 'content', 'pageHeading' etc

 return $sections['sidebar']; // this will only return whats in the sidebar section of the view
```

Using `compact()` should get your where you need, and is the key.

Comment: very strange! I understand ur reply and i am totally with u, but it throught the same error ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined variable: data (View: /home2/wlimaser/public_html/rimborsi/resources/views/includes/sidebar.blade.php) (View: /home2/wlimaser/public_html/rimborsi/resources/views/includes/sidebar.blade.php)

Comment: OK.  The solution to the issue #1 is to use compact as above.  But, there may be a compounding issue with how the view is being called.  Try:  copy all of the view code from **sidebar.blade.php** into **@section('sidebar')** and remove **@include('includes.sidebar')**.  This is a test.  If this works, you can either leave it this way, or refactor the view render against the **sidebar** view file only.

Comment: Yeah sorry!! I tried access in foreach loop to a column that i didnt specify in select :D This works, and is also better ur solution of remove that includes.sidebar.......now i dont understand why it put the refreshed html of sidebar in the tbody of a table that i have in  @include('includes.main')  but i think this is another problem :S . Thx a lot